# Object notation react map groupby

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react

I am trying to group an object by division. I am not able to figure out how to map them. 
So the object notation is something like below
[image: obj={Division:[Assignee:]}]

```
> Object.keys(this.state.ListItems).map(function(item,key)



> State:
> {"Division1":[{"Assignee":[{"Title":""}],"Division":"","DueDate":"","Id":"","Author":{"Title":""},"Email":""}]}

render:{Object.keys(this.state.ListItems).map(function(item,key){item.Division}
```

[image]

How do I render this so that it renders as below:
 Grouping by division basically.

=> Division1
  Assignee
  Author
  DueDate
=> Division1
  Assignee
  Author
  DueDate

I am modifying initial object using below algorithm

```
     // Accepts the array and key
  const groupBy = (array, key) => {
    // Return the end result
    return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
      // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
      (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
        currentValue
      );
      // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
      return result;
    }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
  };
  const personGroupedByColor = groupBy(AssignmentList, 'Division');
```

Update: I was able to display the divisions, now I have to work on mapping the arrays inside each Division.

```
Object.keys(this.state.ListItems).map(function(item,key){return(<div>{item}</div>)})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically do a map within a map, to loop through the divisions, then through the array within each division.  Something like this:

```
Object.keys(divisionGroupItems).map(function(division,key){
    return(<div>{division}
    { 
        divisionGroupItems[division].map(function(item, key) {
            return (<div>{item.Assignee} {item.DueDate}</div>);
        })
    }
    </div>);
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I just figured it out. For any one looking for the same,here is my code.{Object.keys(this.state.ListItems).length===1 ? null: Object.keys(this.state.ListItems).map((key,i)=>{return <div>
                <div key={key}><p>{key}</p></div>
                  {this.state.ListItems[key].map((item) => {
                        return <div><p>{item.Assignee}</p></div>;
                  })}
           </div>})}